# Make Angular Controller Run Continuously Through Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope

In short, I am wondering if it possible to make an Angular controller pick up where it left off after the page is refreshed.

To give more details, suppose I have a controller that is responsible for running timers on several DOM items on that page. I click start, timer runs until I stop it. Now, when the page is refreshed, the timer and all values are re-set to zero. How could I make them continue from where they were immediately before the refresh event? In fact, is there a way to account even for the time it took for the page to refresh?

Currently, Angular is doing the timing. Should I try to switch timing to Node side?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no persistence of state between page loads in javascript you would need to store the timer state. localStorage would be one option

Not clear if timer is working towards a fixed time or tracking elapsed time. Store wht works best to allow you to reactivate when service runs again

Comment: The timer starts at zero and counts up. However, the reverse situation will also be added. Hence, the answer is both :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you try to switch the timer values to Node's side. That's the only way you can get the timers really updated and synchronized with your server.

I do not encourage that you store the timer values on storage, you will never have a reliable data, since the user can easily modify it.

Comment: What do you mean by "storage?" If I tried storing values in database?

Comment: Local or Session storage. That are browser storage, like cookies.